# Why is LEA 0x89AB(%A0),%A0 an Illegal Instruction in 68000 assembly

Tags: assembly, 68000

[image]

here is the programming card :
https://files.fm/u/7pfmqca9

Why is LEA 0x89AB(%A0),%A0 an Illegal Instruction in 68000 assembly?

Comment: It seems you have mistaken x86 for `m68k` (Motorola 68000). They are different in plenty of details. Register A0 is from m68k but not x86.

Comment: @Netch: m68k has an LEA instruction with the same mnemonic as x86.  [Difference between LEA and MOVE.L?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10740222)

Comment: @PeterCordes see question edit history: it was initially containing "86" in all text. That's why I noticed wrong register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the examples given, I infer that a 16-bit immediate is sign extended. From that, I would guess that the 16-bit offset in the indexed addressing mode is also signed. Thus, 0x89ab is an invalid offset, because it doesn't fit in a 16-bit signed number.